# List question "on hold" in the "off-topic" section in Help?

Tags: feature-request

Could the off-topic section in Help include a link that showed some/all of the questions which have been put 'on hold' because they were deemed 'off topic'?

That would give new users a very quick view of what's off-topic, and we don't have to maintain or invent the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we should link the [current thread for on vs off-topic](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225/updated-6-aug-what-is-on-topic-lets-improve-our-faq-help?cb=1) to the [help: on-topic page](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: ...that's my plan. I was going to edit the on-topic page to have a list of the topics that are voted above-zero, off-topic list topics zero-and-below; both pages linked to the Q in meta.

Comment: Ya, it's obvious... but by posting an answer, I'm making the decision public and open for community debate...