# Whatever happened to expanding on-topic subjects?

Tags: discussion

Quite some time ago, a question was posted here [asking for opinions on whether our list of acceptable topics should be updated](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/813/disagree-with-what-is-on-off-topic-here-join-the-discussion-community-feedback).  There were several suggestions that seem to have received support, but to date, nothing has changed.

What does it take to make a change? We will never have consensus, but it seems that some of the ideas had a good response from the active participants on this SE.  Do the moderators need some threshold of upvotes?

**EDIT**

I find it frustrating (and a little sad) that after 30 days, no moderator has commented one way or another on this question,

**ANOTHER EDIT**

It's now been more than 60 days, and no moderator has commented one way or another on this question,

Comment: They don't care.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to reply to this earlier, Ron. Life has been weird the last months, not just for me, but for everybody. I read this, but decided I needed to discuss this with the other mods, and that's not that easy at this moment. I should have replied earlier, I can try to see what we can do now, but there are a number of difficulties involved (one of them being the amount of time I have, but there are others).

Comment: Ron, I apologize as I did start that process, then life got a bit crazy for me and I know I didn't follow through. I did email SE about stepping down as mod around that time and they suggested I stay on even if I am not very active. In the past two years, life has been even crazier and I don't need even one hand to count the number of times I have spent any length of time on any SE site. I really didn't expect to still have my diamond when I just hopped back on the site. Seems I may need to email them again about replacing me.

Comment: @ViníciusFerrão, the mods here do care and have spent FAR more time volunteering here to help this community than nearly any other user has spent here in entirety. Saying they don't care is a great disservice to mods across the SE network.

Comment: @YLearn We're all glad to see you surfaced.  We were getting a bit concerned about you.