# Stack recommendation

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Network Engineering Stack Exchange post: [Subnetting & Routing Path](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/63087/subnetting-routing-path)

I'm stuck in trying to learn subnets and thought I'd find some help here, but was told that my question wasn't allowed here.  Is there somewhere else I can ask for help on this?  I'm not looking for an easy answer.  I'm just trying to learn the process and see where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Stack Exchange isn't the place to ask for recommendations.  You can Google something like "subnetting tutorial" and get many options.

Answer (score 2):

There are many references for learning this online. One of the best offerings we have here along these lines is [this question and it's associated answers](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7106/33). The answers are quite involved and cover many associated topics in a fairly large amount of detail.

It may also help you to understand why homework questions are considered off topic by this community so please see [this question](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/257/33) and [this question](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/530/33) as examples discussed here before. You will likely find the question you asked is not appropriate for any site on the network in it's current form for similar reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and info.