# What tools used by Network Engineers on-topic

Tags: discussion

Are common tools used by network engineers on-topic. Specifically referencing post “[Monitor http traffic in Mac OSX](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5930/monitor-http-traffic-in-mac-osx)”.

Answer (score -1):

My thoughts are ‘no’, because it must be about a device that has a core concept in network engineering.  Mike Pennington referenced “[What is ON-topic? Let's improve our FAQ/Help](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225/what-is-on-topic-lets-improve-our-faq-help/239#239)”.  My objection to this is that it just doesn’t have anything to do with *engineering* a *network* in any sense of the term.

A couple questions go through my head when I make a decision about ‘on/off topic’ decisions:

1. Does this have anything to do with [implementing, maintaining, troubleshooting, optimizing, clarifying] a network device or infrastructure?
2. Is this a better fit for another Stack and could it get a better answer there?
3. Does this have more to do with an infrastructure device, than a server?

All 3 are ‘no’.  1) This is about an end-user device. 2) This would fit perfect in ServerFault/SuperUser. 3) No, it has to do with a server/system, not an infrastructure device.

I want to make it a habit to defer questions that are a better fit for another Stack, to another Stack.  Accepting questions that fit ‘tools used by Network Engineers” in the broadest sense is going to riddle this Stack with questions that belong elsewhere; Network Engineers use *everything*, and the last thing we need is questions about how to develop a `sed` script that translates Cisco interface configurations to Juniper (which I’ve done).

`tcpdump` is available on every platform. Figuring out why tcpdump isn’t working is beyond the scope of network engineering.  Figuring out why packets aren’t reaching their intended destination is.

Comment: For clarity: I think MikeP was referring to the section, in that meta question, where tools used by network engineers are explicitly on-topic. In the Help, What's on topic? we explicitly give a wireshark Q as an example. Tools, are simply on-topic due to the community members not close-voting the Q you're talking about, and because the definitively up-voted the Tools answer in that meta question.

Comment: @CraigConstantine I agree that questions that have a core concept in network engineering belong here (like the referenced Wireshark OSPF Link State ID filter), but questions about how to get tcpdump to format content a certain way doesn't belong, that is not a tool that is `specific` to network engineering.

Comment: -1 because `tcpdump` is on every platform, it's like another tool used by network engineers `ping`.  If you've been a network engineer for long, you know that the network is blamed for everything and we have to be able to efficiently investigate problems.  Knowing how to use tools (such as `tcpdump`, wireshark or `tshark`) is a core competency, and that includes formatting the output of said tools.  If you don't like the question, you can always downvote / vote to close.