# Developer questions

Tags: discussion

Are questions from developers about, for example, writing a routing daemon on topic?  I'm thinking specifically about question like internal application processes rather than how the protocol works.   The on/off topic list is silent on this matter.

Answer (score 6):

> Point of order: Although I'm a pro-tem moderator here, this answer
>   has no special weight/meaning. I urge all the comm members to vote
>   their minds, and if someone disagrees/has-a-better-idea, please post
>   your answer(s) too.

Maybe...

**On Topic:** questions about the protocol design and features. The [Net Prot design/theory](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225/what-is-on-topic-lets-improve-our-faq-help/228#228) I think would cover this.

**Off Topic:** questions about how to write the software to implement network protocols. Other examples of off-topic programming material: how a programming / kernel network API should work, or how to use a programming / kernel API.

Stack Overflow is the place for *all* programming and API questions.

Comment: I was aiming for a more generalized form of the question, rather than that specific post.  I guess I don't have the same visceral reaction to code jockeys as you. ;)

Comment: I am sympathetic to and appreciative of the amount of work you have put into this site.  Perhaps we can deal with this by simply deciding this question.  Programming questions, e.g., how to design or code network protocol functions in applications or utilities are off-topic. If it's policy, then we can point to it and be done.   If no one (else) feels strongly enough to vote yea or nay, then we can make policy based on our votes.