# Can SE auto-add a comment based on the close reason?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

A while back, I started pasting in carefully crafted text clippings before I press the moderator-instant-death-close button. Aside from that being extra work, it obviously doesn't happen when the community 5-vote-closes a question.

(( One is a very welcoming, "sorry this is off topic" and I tried to write a "help vampire; too newbie; we dont do 'help, the internet is borken' questions" version but failed. ))

Is there any way we could write our site specific boiler-plate close comments. This would be a **HUGE** improvement for welcoming new stack users.

Comment: +1 for this, it's too much of a hassle to do this for every downvote. If this not possible, maybe you could consider sharing your texts?

Comment: won't work here as a comment because it's exactly (spare 4 chars) long enough and has embedded links... i'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a close message that does already contain much of that information, so it seems like a bit of a redundancy. We have the ability to edit the generic off topic message, plus define up to three of our own custom off topic close reasons. Currently the generic message reads as follows:

> This question does not appear to be about network engineering within the scope defined in the help center.

Second, I personally prefer to be less canned when possible. I have dusted off a piece of software I hadn't used in a while that allows me to post my comments in a more personalized way.

At present I have just over 30 "fragments" of comments I can quickly string together, with or without additional specific input from me, to provide a more tailored response. Hopefully this helps to provide a more individualized experience, especially to new users.

For example, the most common generic combination I have been using is for home/consumer questions which takes the form of two or three fragments. I first check the user profile to see if this appears to be their first contribution. If so, I start with the welcome message:

> Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community.

Followed by my close reason:

> Unfortunately, NE is a site for network professionals to ask and provide answers about professional networks. Questions about home networks and consumer devices are considered off topic by this community. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details.

And finally a pointer to where their question may be a better fit:

> You could try posting this on a different site on the network, such as [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Naturally, this is a work in progress so it will likely change over time.

Comment: ...wait, we can edit those generic messages? I had no idea we could do that. How?

Comment: @CraigConstantine, if you go to the mod tools (by default brings you to the history tab), click on the "links" tab and you will find "Manage Off-Topic Close Reasons" link. (Not embedding it since most users probably can't access it.)

Comment: I've created a meta [Question for discussing changing this](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/474/lets-edit-our-sites-default-off-topic-close-reason/475).

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, per se, but here's the one comment that I think works pretty well for a generic "sorry, off topic" close boiler plate. It's one long line so you can copy it and get the mark-up too:

```
Welcome to NE, the stack for Qs about professional Net Eng. I apologize for this paste-in comment, but I have to use this a LOT. Have you read our [What Can I Ask Here?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) We worked REALLY hard on it, and your Q does not fit [What Our Community Decided](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225) would be On-topic. Disagree? Please ask a Q in our parallel [Meta Net Eng](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com) including a link back to this Q and explain exactly where you feel it fits in our On-Topic list.
```

Here it is rendered so you can see how it looks in situ:

Welcome to NE, the stack for Qs about professional Net Eng. I apologize for this paste-in comment, but I have to use this a LOT. Have you read our [What Can I Ask Here?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) We worked REALLY hard on it, and your Q does not fit [What Our Community Decided](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225) would be On-topic. Disagree? Please ask a Q in our parallel [Meta Net Eng](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com) including a link back to this Q and explain exactly where you feel it fits in our On-Topic list.

The whole thing (source code) is whittled to within four chars of the max length for a comment. If we were allowed more space in auto-comment-on-close, we could expand this to link to some more Meta questions/discussion, or other help as well.

Comment: If you're struggling for a few more letters, I believe `[meta]` is a short-cut to what's written above.  I think.  At least that's how it works with `[chat]`.