# SE Feature Req: Can we edit our "too broad" close message?

Tags: feature-request

**Background**

We do not want to have to add comments when closing things. (It slows us down.)

We've already [had a discussion](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/477/additional-closed-reason-not-enough-details) about adding an additional close reason for "not enough details". This discussion occurred because we have a significant number of questions that MIGHT be ok/on-topic/answerable if the OP just went into more detail. So it was thought that adding a new reason would allow us to provide a more useful explanation. However, I don't feel we reached a consensus, so we've not added a new close reason.

(And honestly, I think "too broad" is close enough to what we need; We don't need "too broad" AND "please add more details".)

NE has a spectacular [NE Question Checklist](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292/network-engineering-question-checklist) in Meta that OP should be led to when their question is not-quite-good-enoug-but-maybe-with-more-info.

**Request**

Can we make editable, or can SE one-off-edit for us, the message for the Too Broad close reason? A tweak to:

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be
>   too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set
>   or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs. Also
>   see [Network Engineering Question
>   Checklist](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292/network-engineering-question-checklist)
>   on our Meta site.