# Question about tools marked as off-topic

Tags: discussion, off-topic, etiquette

My [question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/29930/joining-two-layer-3-interfaces-for-failover) was marked as off-topic. This question is **not** about a home network. However, while reading the [rules](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) of NE, I see there is a requirement for the question to be about:

- tools used by network professionals.

And meet the following requirement:

- under your direct control.

Is my question really off-topic? Do I misunderstand what a tool is? If so, is it possible to move this question somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

I see the question as more of an end-device configuration problem, which is off-topic. Also, for network devices, a big criterion is the paid support option. See [this answer](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/568/8499) for more explanation.

Comment: OK, I agree that it doesn't match the paid support criterion (if I had paid support, I would probably ask there). However, I intend to develop a router that sits between the two providers on one side, and an end-device on the other. Is it possible to move this to, say, Server Fault, or should I simply create a new question there?

Comment: You don't need to have paid support, but the product needs to have that option. For instance, Cisco devices have the option of paid support, but many people asking questions here do not actually have the paid support. The moderators may move it since there is an answer. Unfortunately, I don't have that power.

Comment: Since there were answers worth preserving I've moved the question to [sf].