# Questions about professional network principles, used on home networking equipment

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I asked [this](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/44449/active-even-bandwidth-splitting-with-dd-wrt) question earlier today. It was about DD-WRT which may be firmware for consumer grade routers, but is also used occasionally in enterprise I believe because the functionality borders on what is available in commercial grade hardware, making (i.m.o) the only difference being the relative quality of the hardware and how often the device needs a restart. My question is about bandwidth sharing which is something that every IT department I have worked in has had equipment to control, in at least one case using DD-WRT on one of the higher end consumer grade routers.

Should the off topic rule be so broad to include principles that professional networking use, that are also occasionally used in home networking? I realise that including home networking would lead to questions about basic networking that would probably be best solved on subsites like superuser, but shouldn't questions about somewhat advanced networking that I believe borders on enterprise networking be asked on a site with an  advanced/professional networking knowledge base, not a generic PC problem site like Superuser?

Comment: DD-WRT is not supported by its vendor with optional, paid support, which is a requirement for [networkengineering.se] (see the [help/on-topic]). Please see [this answer](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/568/8499). It is supported on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] for a personal network.

Comment: Thanks again for your respectful answer Ron, but can't quite see the logic in only supporting this kind of question should the device have paid support. I would then logically pursue a fix through the paid support and I would contend 90% of the time get an answer through that channel. It really disappoints me that a question about (i.m.h.o) a rather complicated network settings change would be relegated to a SE site with the kind of questions and answers that I have seen on SuperUser.

Comment: It's not a requirement that you actually have paid support, only that the vendor offers it. As the answer to the question to which I linked says, it is an imperfect solution, and we are open to suggestions for a better way to draw the line. So far, there have been no suggestions that have gotten community consensus.

Comment: I unfortunately don't have a good way to define a line that would separate questions about enterprise networking principles, from consumer-type networking questions, if that is even what the community wishes to "let over the line". Nor,in the position I am in currently,would I feel comfortable putting my vote in for the next guy on what should and should not be answered on this SE sub-site. I would however vote for "Network Engineering" to be changed to "Enterprise Networking" as the site name, as the former doesn't imply what I have subsequent to asking a question been told is a valid subject

Comment: I wasn't actually involved in setting up or naming the site, and it would certainly make things easier if SE had a way to clearly delineate the Professional sites like [networkengineering.se] or [sf]. I can't count the number of times that I have been told that nobody reads (or should need to read) the [help/on-topic], where the first line says, "_**Network Engineering Stack Exchange is for asking questions about professionally managed networks in a business environment.**_" I appreciate that you didn't get angry or abusive they way some do.