# Question put on hold

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Network Engineering Stack Exchange post: [Linux VRF and Multicast IP](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/51888/linux-vrf-and-multicast-ip)

I don't believe that this is off-topic, this is not about host/server configuration.

Comment: Isn't this running on a Linux server? You are asking about the host interfaces, and why the OS is behaving is a certain way. This question is appropriate for [unix.se], [ubuntu.se], [su], or [sf] (for a business network, the same business requirement as for [networkengineering.se]).

Comment: The fact that Linux is the OS does not mean that it is being used as a server, this device will ultimately be used by ISPs in their core network as a bridge router, with network processing offloaded to the hardware.  I am using OSPF to build the routing table, but the customer wants VRF support  so I need VRFs to work in both the hardware and within Linux.  Since OSPF sends its hello messages to a multicast address, the packets make it out of the box when we're not using VRFs, but when we do multicast looks like it's blocked.

Comment: I'll concede that it is an issue specific to Linux, however, this is no different to asking a question about an issue specific to a Cisco router or any other network device since I am using it as a router in an ISP network.  Cisco IOS XE is built on Linux, for example.

Comment: If you notice the caveat on the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page, it says that a device manufacturer must offer optional, paid support for a device to be on-topic here. I don't see that Xubuntu offers that. As I explained multiple times, there are other SE sites where this question is on-topic.

Comment: It says **_hardware_ that has a paid support option from the manufacturer**.  The _hardware_ is supported; the software is not.  I did have a look around before I posted the question, I decided that Network Engineering was where it fit best, and where I was likely to get the answer I was looking for.

Comment: That's the gist of the caveat. The OS of the hardware needs support. [This answer](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/568/8499) explains the reasoning. Primarily, "_The key difference is that vendors who provide paid support for their own product have a vested interest in the product._" Linux, and in particular, Ubuntu, have other SE sites (SE typically discourages duplication) where experts in Linux hang out and answer questions, many of whom are network experts. In any case, you may have had an answer by now if you asked on the correct SE site instead of arguing here.

Comment: I put this question On-Hold two days ago, and I have yet to see a single reopen vote. I just double-checked, and there have been none for your question. I check the review queue often, so I, or another moderator, should see any reopen votes soon after they happen.

Comment: I'm having a discussion, not arguing, I'm trying to understand your logic.  I do feel like you are splitting hairs since I could have just as easily written "I am attempting to use VRFs in Cisco's AXP running in a 2800 series router" which would be exactly the same situation.  In any case, I think my question is dead in the water now, I'll go elsewhere.

Comment: You cannot compare the two situations. We have plenty of Cisco experts here, and many have contracts allowing them to contact Cisco TAC with such questions. You are much more likely to find Linux experts on one of the Linux sites. You are asking about how/why Linux behaves the way it does, not how Cisco IOS behaves the way it does. Those are very different OSes; one is supported here, and the other is not.

Comment: In the context of my previous comment AXP _is_ Linux

Comment: But that doesn't run on the obsolete (EoS and EoL) 2800 series routers, which ran IOS, as I said in my answer. Cisco has a version of Linux for some of its devices, and it provides paid support for that. In any case, I have seen no support from this community for your question.

Comment: I have moved the question to a different site; I do think this community should start to embrace other devices, though, your attitude seems very rigid compared to how fluid the industry is.

Comment: I'm only trying to do what the community has asked, and I am trying to help you because your question would have just languished with no activity, as I have seen happen before. I want you to get an answer, but that was unlikely to happen on [networkengineering.se].