# How a question about routing configuration is off-topic here?

Tags: discussion, support, off-topic

I asked this question:
[How to filter unused routes in MikroTik routers?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/74527/how-to-filter-unused-routes-in-mikrotik-routers)

But this question marked as off-topic I wonder how a question about routing and configuring routers at an enterprise-level is off-topic here?

> servers operating as a router/switch/firewall;
> design or theory of protocols used to operate a network (e.g. IP, TCP, routing protocols, STP, etc);

Comment: I read your question... I think you'll be perfectly happy to assign at least two routers as OSPF ASBRs and announce two default routes as OSPF External Type-1 (Cisco calls them E1) routes.  Of course the routers you assign to originate the defaults must be able to get to any IP prefix you require.

Answer (score 1):

That question was first closed because it is too broad, lacking enough detail to be able to answer. It needs a good network description or diagram, the network device models, the network device configurations, any logs, debugs, etc. You can refer to the [Network Engineering Question Checklist](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/292/8499) for guidance on what should be included.

The reason for closure was changed when you admitted that the routers are MikroTik. On the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page, it has a couple of caveats, including:

> hardware that has a paid support option from the manufacturer
> (enterprise/provider class products, some small business class
> devices);

Unfortunately, MikroTik does not offer that, so its devices are off-topic for NE. [This Meta answer](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/568/8499) goes into more detail about that:

> The key difference is that vendors who provide paid support for their
> own product have a vested interest in the product.

-and-

> Further, devices with paid support options often also provide better
> documentation.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I was searching for a feature in OSPF and I did not care about the specific vendor. can you tell me where should I ask such a broad question?

Comment: Unfortunately, SE does not allow recommendations for off-site resources, which is understandable because SE does not want to promote its competition. I would need to search for such a site, just as you need to search for it, but I really have no incentive to spend my time on that. You could start with your manufacturer's site, where it may have a place to ask such questions.

Comment: I find my answer now. but I was asking about OSPF which is a routing protocol and I was asking about a feature in this protocol so I do not think this is too broad. when I read the on-topic section I supposed that this question is on-topic because of the part that I quoted here.