# Is this post off topic, and if so why?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Network Engineering Stack Exchange post: [Static routes and multiple routers](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/30399/static-routes-and-multiple-routers)

Is my post off-topic and if so why?

It is about enterprise equipment in an enterprise environment.

Answer (score 1):

I thinks it's off-topic because the primary question is about the consumer-grade router in a home network (see this answer: https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/234/8499 and the one which follows it):

> If the Ubiquiti USG is NATing the outbound traffic, then why do I
>       need a static route in my friends router that refers to the
>       172.27.0.0/16 subnet, isn't this out of context?

The second and third questions may be on-topic, but you need to edit the question to provide the device configurations. I'm not sure why you need to route on the switch; as far as I know, the Ubiquiti can do VLANs. If you want to route on the switch, you should route both VLANs on the switch.

Comment: OK, so what is the determination for what is an enterprise router and what is a consumer router? Ubiquiti market there product as an "Enterprise Gateway Router with Gigabit Ethernet". https://dl.ubnt.com/datasheets/unifi/UniFi_Security_Gateway_DS.pdf

Comment: You couldn't even tell me the brand of your friend's home network router. Your question is about configuring your friend's router. It is a broadband router for his home network. Questions about anything behind that are off-topic. This was a community decision. I have Cisco enterprise-grade equipment for my home, and it is connected to a residential ISP, so any questions I have about my home network is off-topic here.

Comment: The question is not about the other router. The question is about the USG.  In the set up I describe there should be no need to set anything up on the other router. The question is, in that set up why is the USG not functioning properly? why is it necessary to add a static route to the other router when there should be no need for it in the scenario I described. If I connected directly to the internet, then the other router would just be the ISPs router and I wouldn't have any access to it - but the scenario would be essentially the same.

Comment: Actually, "_then why do I need a static route in my friends router that refers to the 172.27.0.0/16 subnet_," that is specifically about your friend's router, and why it won't forward all the traffic to your router. Also, if you read the answer I linked, anything behind your friend's router (including your network) is off-topic. I did answer your other questions, but I can't get into the friend's router or your network's interaction with it on Network Engineering. Super User is the place to ask about home/residential networking.

Comment: Based on what I have seen, if you ask about your office server on Server Fault, and you explain that it is connected through a home network, your question will be summarily moved to Super User, despite the fact that it is your business server.

Comment: I edited your question to remove the off-topic parts, then I edited my answer to answer the resulting question. You can roll the question back if you don't like it.

Comment: OK. You rolled it back. I answered why you need the static route on your router, but the reason for the static route on your friend's home-network, consumer-grade router is off-topic here. I'm sorry you disagree, but it is a community decision to not allow these types of questions.